# Floating Windows and toolbars on top in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design

I really like to work with floating windows in Photoshop. Especially with compositions it makes it really easy for me to quickly copy paste from different textures on a visual way (instead of trying to remember if I need to open tab **metal_2834fj.jpg** or **metal_238p_.jpg** or **Untitled1** etc.

Is there a way though to have the toolbars **always on top**?

Right now floating documents might be partial hiding essential interface elements. It's workable, but quite annoying still.

I tried to explain myself a bit better in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got two options:

1. **Disable application frame.**

   - `Window > Application frame`
   - If I remember correctly, Windows doesn't have this option. If so, you gotta go with option #2.
2. **Float your toolbars and panels.**

   - You can do it exactly how you would float document tabs. Drag them away from the docked position and let go.

Gif of the second option:
[image]

Comment: Whow. Thanks a lot Joonas, that was quite simple in the end. Never expected to get an answer for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Click twice on the title bar of a photo and it will be behind all bars.

The problem is that you will only have one image at a time. But all your opened images will be as tabs next to each other.

Comment: Hi Rafael, thanks for your answer. That last part I'm trying to avoid :) I like floating windows, becauseit gives me a visual cue to which image is what - instead of filenames like Untitled1, Untitled2, Metal3248.jpg, metal_32745.jpg etc. With tabs I'll have to remember all names.